# PyCharm: shortcut line comment

Tags: pycharm, comments

I know the keyboard shortcut for a **line comment** in Pycharm is `ctrl+slash`.

But it doesn't work when I try it. Does someone knows what I'm doing wrong? Our a suggestion what I can try?

Comment: Are you on a mac? If so it's `CMD + slash`.  Either way, open up `Preferences -> Keymap` and search for `Comment with Line Comment` to see if you accidently changed something.

Comment: @chris No, not mac. I checked the keymap options and ctrl+slash is there, so very weird. If I add my own combination, it works... So that's okay for me. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, found it! Due to my Belgian keyboard layout I should point the shortcut description to `Ctrl + Colon` in stead of `Ctrl + Slash`. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Are you on a MAC or PC? On a MAC it's 'Command+/', which produces:

```
<!---->
```

Answer (score 2):

For all Mac Users you have desperately hoped to find an answer in this post for the problem that the shortcut is not working (for example on German keyboards):

1. Goto Preferences -> Keymap -> Code -> Comment with Line Comment
2. Add new shortcut: Shift + Command + 7

... and it will work.

Comment: Highly underrated answer